# React Admin - Get current value in a form

Tags: react-admin

I am having big troubles getting the "updated" value of a record in an edit form. I always get the initial record values, even though I have an input linked to the right record source, which should update it.

Is there an alternative way to get the values of the SimpleForm ?

I have a simple edit form :

```
<Edit {...props}>
    <SimpleForm>
        <MyEditForm {...props} />
    </SimpleForm>
</Edit>
```

MyEditForm is as follow:

```
class MyEditForm extends React.Component {
    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot) {    
        console.log(prevProps.record.surface, this.props.record.surface); // <-- here is my problem, both values always get the initial value I had when I fetched the resource from API
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <TextInput source="surface" />
                <!-- other fields -->
            </div>
         );
    }
}
```

I usually do it this way to get my updated component's data from other components, but in the very case of a react-admin form, I can't get it to work.

Thanks,

Nicolas

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It really depends on what you want to do with those values. If you want to hide/show/modify inputs based on the value of another input, the [`FormDataConsumer`](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Inputs.html#linking-two-inputs) is the preferred method:

For example:

```
import { FormDataConsumer } from 'react-admin';

const OrderEdit = (props) => (
    <Edit {...props}>
        <SimpleForm>
            <SelectInput source="country" choices={countries} />
            <FormDataConsumer>
                {({ formData, ...rest }) =>
                     <SelectInput 
                         source="city"
                         choices={getCitiesFor(formData.country)}
                         {...rest}
                     />
                }
            </FormDataConsumer>
        </SimpleForm>
    </Edit>
);
```

You can find more examples in the [Input](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Inputs.html) documentation. Take a look at the [Linking Two Inputs](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Inputs.html#linking-two-inputs) and [Hiding Inputs Based On Other Inputs](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Inputs.html#hiding-inputs-based-on-other-inputs).

However, if you want to use the form values in methods of your `MyEditForm` component, you should use the reduxForm [selectors](https://redux-form.com/7.4.2/docs/api/selectors.md/#-code-getformvalues-formname-string-code-returns-code-state-gt-formvalues-object-code-). This is safer as it will work even if we change the key where the reduxForm state is in our store.

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { getFormValues } from 'redux-form';

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    recordLiveValues: getFormValues('record-form')(state)
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MyForm);
```

Comment: Perfect answer, thank you. This is indeed the second case I currently face.
Do you have any idea of how I can programmatically change a value in a function as well?

Comment: Use redux form action creators

Comment: Thanks for the info, although I'm having big troubles understanding how to adapt mapDispatchToProps (following this doc https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options) to React Admin. If you have a very short example, that would be perfect. Thanks a lot ;)

Comment: This is outdated, react-admin does not use redux-form, it use react-final-form. I am trying with a `FormDataConsumer` to display twice a `DateField`, except one format the date time to a particular timezone and is `disabled`. I always get the `formData.someDate` from the previous form, I need to select twice the value to get this field updated. How can I access values within the form in order to format my field correctly each time the value change ?

Answer (score 3):

I found a working solution :

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    recordLiveValues: state.form['record-form'].values
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MyForm);
```

When mapping the form state to my component's properties, I'm able to find my values using :

```
recordLiveValues.surface
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use `redux` or you use other global state like me (recoil, etc.)
You can create custom-child component inside FormDataConsumer here example from me

```js
// create FormReceiver component
const FormReceiver = ({ formData, getForm }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    getForm(formData)
  }, [formData])
  return null
}
```

```js
// inside any admin form
const AdminForm = () => {
   const formState = useRef({}) // useRef for good performance not rerender
   const getForm = (form) => {
     formState.current = form
   }

   // you can access form by using `formState.current`

   return (
     <SimpleForm>
       <FormDataConsumer>
         {({ formData, ...rest }) => (
           <FormReceiver formData={formData} getForm={getForm} />
         )}
       </FormDataConsumer>
     </SimpleForm>
   )
}
```